# Httplib2 exception raised when calling Twilio from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, docker, twilio

I'm trying to send an SMS message via Twilio from some Python code running in a Docker container.  The container was built from an Ubuntu image with Python 2.7 and the latest twilio-python helper library.  When calling the TwilioRestClient messages.create() function, I get the traceback below. Also, I have confirmed via curl that I can reach the url "api.twilio.com" as indicated in the traceback from this container. Any ideas?

Code being used...

```
import argparse
import requests
import time
import smtplib
from datetime import datetime
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

def sendText( ToNumber, smsMsg):

# put your own credentials here

ACCOUNT_SID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

AUTH_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

FromNumber = '+nnnnnnnnnnn'

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

client.messages.create(to = ToNumber,from_ = FromNumber,body = smsMsg,)

return True
```

Traceback...

```
File "./siteminder3.py", line 15, in sendText
  message = client.messages.create(to=ToNumber,from_=FromNumber,body=smsMsg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/messages.py", line 122, in create
  return self.create_instance(kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 365, in create_instance
  data=transform_params(body))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 200, in request
  resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 152, in make_twilio_request
  resp = make_request(method, uri, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 117, in make_request
  resp, content = http.request(url, method, headers=headers, body=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
  (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
  (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1278, in _conn_request
  raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at api.twilio.com
```

Comment: Add the python code you use

Comment: This is pretty much verbatim from the Twilio documentation.  Also, the credentials are working from another app where I'm using a restful post.  So I'm pretty certain that it's not related to authentication. Apologies for the bad formatting - not sure how to fix that.

Comment: update the question, don't add code in comments

Comment: Does your container have external network connectivity?

Comment: Yes to connectivity.  I added a requests.get("http://api.twilio.com"... and received back a 200 status code.

Comment: so I figured out how to use pdb (yay!). from within python, if I run 'httplib2.Http().request("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<myauthcode>/Messages.json"...) it raises the httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find server at api.twilio.com.  From the bash shell, if I run curl with the same url, I just get an auth error, which is expected since I haven't provided the auth header. Hmmm...